# Given a table, place in the chairs

Tags: code-golf

## Challenge

You will be given a table as input, drawn with ASCII `|` and `_`. Your task is to set the chairs around it.

## Example

Input:

```
 ____
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|____|
```

Output:

```
 _^_^_
<     >
|     |
<     >
|     |
<_ _ _>
  v v
```

Those chairs are made of `<>` and `v^`.

Another example:

The line must have as many chairs as possible in it.

```
  _____
 |     |_____
 |           |
 |           |
 |           |
 |      _____|
 |_____|


  _^_^_
 <     |_^_^_
 |           >
 <           |
 |           |
 <      _ _ _>
 |_ _ _| v v
   v v
```

There must be spaces between every chair. And `>_^_^_<` is invalid, it should be `|_^_^_|`.

```
  _____       _____
 |     |_____|     |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |      ___________|
 |_____|


  _^_^_       _^_^_
 <     |_^_^_|     >
 |                 |
 <                 >
 |                 |
 <      _ _ _ _ _ _>
 |_ _ _| v v v v v
   v v
```

No chairs may be on the inside of a "donut".

```
  _________________
 |      _____      |
 |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |
 |     |_____|     |
 |_________________|


  _^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_
 <      _____      >
 |     |     |     |
 <     |     |     >
 |     |_____|     |
 <_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _>
   v v v v v v v v
```

`^` and `v` prioritise `<` and `>`. No chair on it's own (it has to have at least one `|` or `_` in the row).

```
  _________________
 |      _____      |
 |     |     |     |
 |     |     |_____|
 |     |_____
 |___________|


  _^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_
 <      _ _ _      >
 |     | v v |     |
 <     >     <_ _ _>
 |     |_^_^_  v v
 <_ _ _ _ _ _|
   v v v v v
```

This is code golf, so shortest code wins.

Comment: I am confused, why are the chairs embedded into the table from sides ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, your original sandbox post had a space between the vertical table line and the chair line. Just like there is a little space between the horizontal table lines and the chairs.

Comment: @Optimizer only the base ones have a space - the top ones `_^_` are one line. When I changed from `[]` I changed it to being in the edge.

Comment: Why is there no `>` on the last line of last example ?

Comment: @Optimizer edited

Comment: it looks like that chairs are placed with 1 distance with each other , but any input's surrounding is not dividable by 2 . how the program should start puting chairs . clockwise or anti-clock wise ? from top right corner , top left corner etc ?

Comment: also i think there is a problem in third sample - there is an extra space between second and third "top" chairs - and also in last example , bottom-right corner

Comment: The chairs make it look spiky.

Comment: The first test case seems to be broken.  The input is only 4 wide and the output is 5.

Comment: Am I safe in assuming, from the examples, that a chair cannot be placed on either side of a concave corner? The examples have some on the side of a convex corner.

Comment: @gnovice correct

Answer (score 33):

## Python 2, <s>1033</s> <s>1007</s> <s>924</s> <s>879</s> <s>829</s> <s>787</s> <s>713</s> <s>699</s> <s>692</s> <s>691</s> <s>688</s> <s>687</s> <s>672</s> <s>670</s> <s>664</s> <s>659</s> <s>654</s> <s>648</s> <s>643</s> <s>642</s> <s>630</s> <s>625</s> <s>623</s> <s>620</s> <s>570</s> <s>560</s> <s>554</s> <s>545</s> <s>518</s> <s>514</s> <s>513</s> <s>510</s> <s>505</s> <s>492</s> <s>476</s> <s>454</s> <s>451</s> 443 bytes

*6 bytes saved thanks to [Riley](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57100/riley)*

*6 bytes saved thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)*

Since this question is over a year old and still has no answers I thought I'd give it a try.

```python
n,i,o,u="\nI _";R=lambda x:range(1,x-1)
b=open(i).read()
s=b.split(n)
z=max(map(len,s))+3
a=[list(i+x.ljust(z,i))for x in[i]+s+[i]]
for x in R(len(a))*len(b):
 A=a[x];B=a[x+1];C=a[x-1]
 for y in R(z):
    D=A[y-1:y+2];k=B[y];j=A[y+1]
    if(i in[C[y],k]+D+(k==u)*B[y-1:y+2]or"V"==j)&(A[y]==o):A[y]=i
    if"|"==A[y]==C[y]:A[y]={i:"|",j:">",A[y-1]:"<"}[i]
    if[u]*3==D:A[y],B[y]={i:u+k,C[y]:"^"+k,k:" V"}[i]
print n.join(`y`[2::5]for y in a).replace(i,o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#lVTNb5swFD/Xf4XlSYsdnEi02gXmSU1z2bWHXqiXmjadTAhEkEgk8/72zObTQKJ272A/P36/5/dlQjaZTABcVQIUrKTZVxcE2mLZh2Q15muj5aIBlHrHrqCqF0QvKNWsqsF3bMtjB1bX2RB2VFXf21Lrozk3MdlUO@dO1CBnBW2Msq8BavWxqCu@FQDgQoMu96bsTxPIoAVDrT6DrlKDdZzlGD4Kvefbgo9Hqh96C7fyawdjHLuq4XZabTvV/8BHlWmGsoXXXRxUXg22Bn7F7QdwqwifgCs4GO7@U7Tgdn/G8HbUwYWuqN4D6Y0quPwQFNA/mXNCJU3pgaHn5CdcIf@RxWIbvglYeJlIfq@xS4uZS8CXkKW7dYIlmWdr8YYJyFk4z3ex3OOEgBPbigJvxQ7H64TmhDh3QLAglvkeS6eYx9FBaycqCXlPM1hAmQSSO7mjVw4aE3w0dCwImZo9JB6A90wEBfcXZnNc7j8YZeZyAA3rWLFOGnmzZPfBceZ6R@eW@xu2CI7cj4xN08CNfMfS3PqgzXTDnaWDN4wdyHTRktIMPSHGIvIVaxZnLCVeqUhDR0p/q@zGR/Xlj/S0nUYe@oFoeT330Hf0V6dlOMGBT@8YW5ZguqgZB2dDSxfoF9LqxkPwqaLsMpnsYTKPUpngl@NLcOt533ibqDDF38XidY1118j5/A8)

The program reads the table a file named `I` and prints the table with its chairs to `std::out`.  I was not sure about a bunch of the edge cases so I took my best judgement (whatever took the least effort) but it seems to pass all the test cases.  Some of the outputs don't match exactly but they all have the same number of chairs.

### Explanation

The first line pretty simply sets up some definitions that will save us bytes in the future:

*(I will unpack these macros for readability in future lines)*

```python
n,i,o="\nI ";R=lambda x:range(1,x-1)
```

Then we will open a file named `I` because we already have a variable that is short for that so it saves a few bytes.

```python
b=open("I").read().split("\n")
```

We split along newlines to create a list of strings (The rows of the image)

```python
s=b.split(n)
```

I then find the length of the longest line so that I can pad all lines to that length.  (I also add 3 because we need a bit of additional padding)

```python
 z=max(map(len,s))+3
```

Then we perform the actual padding and create a border of `I` characters around the edge.  This is because we will need to tell the difference between the inside and the outside of the shape later on.  We will also change the data type from a list of strings to a list of list of characters (length 1 strings).

```python
a=[list("I"+x.ljust(z,"I"))for x in["I"]+s+["I"]]
```

The next line is just another byte saving definition.

*(I will also unpack this one)*

```python
B=R(len(a))
```

Now we want to spread `I` characters to everywhere outside of the shape.  We can do this with a pseudo-cellular automaton.  Each `I` will spread to any adjacent   characters.  We could loop until the automaton stabilizes however this cannot take more iterations than there are characters so we just loop through every character in `b` (the original input)

```python
for _ in b:
```

For each iteration we want to pass over every character in the 2D list (excluding the outermost padding)

```python
 for x in range(1,len(a)-1):
    A=a[x]  #<--Another definition I will fill in for clarity
    for y in range(1,z-1):
```

For each position we run the following code:

```python
if("I" in[a[x+1][y],a[x-1][y]]+a[x][y-1:y+2])&(a[x][y]==" "):a[x][y]=" "
```

Lets break this down.

We have an if with two conditions separated by a `&` (bitwise `and`)

The first one simply checks if there is an `I` in any of the adjacent cells and the second one just checks if the current cell is a `" "`.  If we pass those conditions we set the current cell to be an `I`.

---

Now that we have determined the outside and inside of the shape we can start to place the chairs around the table.

Once again we loop through all of the cells (and set some more shorthands)

```python
for x in range(1,len(a)-1):
 A=a[x]
 for y in range(1,z-1):
        k=a[x+1][y]
```

Now here's my favorite part.  If you have trudged through my boring, mostly definition based, golfing so far I am going to reward you with a nice tidbit of clever golfing (if I do say so myself).

A little background in python:

In Python if you attempt to assign an dictionary key twice it asigns the latter one.  For example

```python
>>> {1:"a",1:"b"}[1]
'b'
```

We will abuse this property to assign the current cell to a particular character.

The first condition is

```python
if["_"]*3==a[x][y-1:y+2]:a[x][y],a[x+1][y]={"I":"_"+a[x+1][y],a[x-1][y]:"^ ",a[x+1][y]:" V"}["I"]
```

If the cell is in the middle of an edge of 3 `_` characters we will reassign the current cell and the cell below it.  We will assign it to the result of indexing an overloaded dictionary by `I`.  We first set our default with the pair `"I":"_"+a[x+1][y]` this means if there is no change we will assign the two cells back to their original values.  Next we add the pair `a[x-1][y]:"^ "`.  This wont do anything (important) unless the cell above the current one (`a[x-1][y]`) is filled with an `I`.  If it has an `I` in it it will override the default telling us to place a chair at the current cell.  Next we move on to the cell below the current cell if that cell is `I` we again override to place an upwards facing chair below the current spot.

The next condition is a tad simpler

```python
if"|"==a[x][y]==a[x-1][y]:a[x][y]={"I":"|",A[y+1]:">",A[y-1]:"<"}["I"]
```

We check if the current cell and the cell above it are both `|`.  If so we set up a dictionary.

The first pair in the dictionary `"I":"|"` sets the default.  Since we are going to access the key `I` if `I` does not get reassigned it will default back to `|` (the character it already is) and do nothing.

We the add the two keys `A[y+1]:">",A[y-1]:"<"` If either of the two cells to the left and right are `I` then it will reassign the current cell to a chair pointing in the direction of the outside.

---

Now we just have to output.  However we can't just print,  there are a couple of housekeeping things we have to do first.  We have to convert back to a string and remove all of the `I`s we created.  This is done in one line.

```python
print "\n".join(`y`[2::5]for y in a).replace("I"," ")
```

Comment: Can't you use a space for the first level of indent, tab for two, a tab and a space for three? That'll save a few bytes.

Comment: This may be the most re-golfed answer.

Comment: Does `i,o="I "` instead of `i="I";o=" "` work?

Comment: @Adnan Yes! Thank you I will add that shortly

Comment: You do not seem to re-use `n`.

Comment: @ErikGolferエリックゴルファー Making `n` costs 4 bytes and saves me 6.  Although I don't use it often it does save 2 bytes.

Comment: @WheatWizard Oh, I didn't see the `split(n)` lol I searched for a second `n` like 5 times or so.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add chairs to the inside of the last test case (the "C" shape).

Comment: @Pietu1998 Thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed the problem

Comment: Let's go over 3 lines folks!